# Как обрезать строку после к?

Tags: php

В переменную $num прилетает число 1к или 1кк или 1ккк. Мне нужно чтобы после к все остальное вырезалось (например чтобы не получилось 1ккм или 1к0), но так как их может быть несколько, функция которую я нашёл (strstr) обрезает только 1 символ ‘к’. Какая есть функция чтобы обрезать все после

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте регулярное выражение:

```
preg_match('/\\d+(?:к){1,3}/', '1кккм', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!